# Element attached to cursors position - positioning breaks on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am moving a div-element attached to the cursors location:

```
var div = $("<div>", { html: "I love you cursor! I will follow you to the ends" +
                             "of the viewport and back!" }).appendTo("body");

$(window).mousemove(function (e)
{
    div.css({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX});
});
```

The above works fine on a page which doesn't exceed the height of the viewport. If the page exceeds viewport height, the positioning of the div-element fails. It seems that pageY/pageX properties don't take scroll-position into account.

The only properties I've found to take scroll-position into account are layerY/layerX, but these are, as far as I can tell, FireFox-only.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(window).scrollLeft()` to the mouse positions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add some css to your div to be considered,
make your div's position absolute

```
var div = $("<div>", { html: "I love you cursor! I will follow you to the ends" +
                         "of the viewport and back!" }).css('position','absolute').css('width','50px').appendTo("body");
```

I think this will work fine

Regards

NiL